# Is it possible to run laptop over direct supply and turn off battery charging?

Tags: battery

Using Ubuntu 12.04 over ASUS K55V
I wonder if it is possible to turn off battery charging and run the system over direct supply???
This function is available with dell laptops in Microsoft Windows. Is this function available within Ubuntu???

Comment: Does **your** ASUS laptop support this in *Windows*?, because you know.. Dell and ASUS aren't the same thing, let alone the Dell reference you use might not have the same components as your ASUS laptop.

Comment: Just a question, why in the world would you ever want to do this?

Comment: @coteyr just to obvious to increase battery life,as battery charging is based on number of counts it charges,if charging is turned off when there is continues AC supply, you can save your battery life :)

Comment: @aks, this is incorrect. That would almost certainly end your battery prematurely (if it's LiON). [See Tip #3](http://www.techatplay.com/?p=61) and [the section about storage](http://blogs.toolbarn.com/2011/02/answering-common-questions-about-li-ion-batteries/) Short version your LiON battery needs a constant power supply to do it's job correctly, "cutting it off" would result in a "discharge" and cause you premature hardware failure.

Comment: well not constant but they should be kept full when ever you can.

Comment: @coteyr, bro its clearly mention to unplug ac adapter while using ur machine,because continuous charging leads to premature death of the battery,it reduces the battery charging count and hence reduces the battery life, do correct me if i am wrong

Comment: but it would have been great to have a circuitry that would auto cut the battery charging after it is fully charged and run the system directly over the input supply and again switches back to battery after the removable of power supply. This would have blessed battery with long life.

Comment: LiON batteries have a shelf life. They do degrade with a cycle but they also "expire" rather used or not.  Where does it say to unplug the AC adapter? I didn't see it in the links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a hardware option and not software. That said the answer is almost 100% no. Even the "dell" laptops don't really turn off charging. At a hardware level LiON battery need a very small charge 100% of the time or they will discharge (or worse, burn out). Most charging circuitry will handle this by discharging and recharging the battery in a tiny increment.

Even Dell laptops would be subject to this requirement if there running LiON batteries.

Comment: If to go into the BIOS settings when your Dell is booting, you should see a setting there to stop the battery charging at a custom threshold, so you don't over-charge.